# How to auto scroll horizontally a div?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this div and I want to scroll automatically, here is the code:

```css
.testimonial-group > .row {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.testimonial-group > .row > .col-xs-4 {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

/* Decorations */
.col-xs-4 { color: #fff; font-size: 48px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 18px; }
.col-xs-4:nth-child(3n+1) { background: #c69; }
.col-xs-4:nth-child(3n+2) { background: #9c6; }
.col-xs-4:nth-child(3n+3) { background: #69c; }
```

```html
<div class="container testimonial-group">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-4">1</div><!--
 --><div class="col-xs-4">2</div><!--
 --><div class="col-xs-4">3</div><!--
 --><div class="col-xs-4">4</div><!--
 --><div class="col-xs-4">5</div><!--
 --><div class="col-xs-4">6</div><!--
 --><div class="col-xs-4">7</div><!--
 --><div class="col-xs-4">8</div><!--
 --><div class="col-xs-4">9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want it to scroll by himself, horizontally.
Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with jquery and `scrollLeft()` function like so for example:

```
    <style>
     .testimonial-group > .row {
      overflow-x: auto;
      white-space: nowrap;
      float:left;
    }
    .testimonial-group > .row > .col-xs-4 {
     float: left;
    }
    . testimonial-group > .row >  .text-center {
    position: fixed;
      bottom: 30px;
      left: 50px;
    }
    </style>

    <script>

    $(window).on('load', function(){
     $('body').animate({
        scrollLeft: $("div").offset().left - 100
      }, 700);
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, how do call the function inside of the div?

Comment: This function as i mentioned above, it doesn't need to be called inside of the div. And the reason for that, is just because the function is executed automatically when the entire page is loaded. That is achieved with the window.load event.

Comment: Also if you want to executed the function by you and not when the page is loaded, then you can add an event listener.  Like so: $("div").on('click', function(){ // and then you just write the scroll function like above });